# Javascript: test regex and assign to variable if it matches in one line

Tags: javascript, regex, var, assign, code-structure

To test if a regex matches and assign it to a variable if it does, or assign it to some default value if it doesn't,
I am currently doing the following:

```
var test = someString.match(/some_regex/gi);
var result = (test) ? test[0] : 'default_value';
```

I was wondering if there is any way to do the same thing in JS with one line of code.

Clarification:
I am not trying to make my code smaller, but rather make it cleaner in places where I am defining a number of variables like so:

```
var foo = 'bar',
    foo2 = 'bar2',
    foo_regex = %I want just one line here to test and assign a regex evaluation result%
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the OR operator (`||`):

```
var result = (someString.match(/some_regex/gi) || ['default_value'])[0];
```

This operator returns its first operand if that operand is truthy, else its second operand. So if `someString.match(/some_regex/gi)` is falsy (i.e. no match), it will use `['default_value']` instead.

This could get a little hacky though, if you want to extract the second capture group, for example. In that case, you can still do this cleanly while initializing multiple variables:

```
var foo = 'bar',
    foo2 = 'bar2',
    test = someString.match(/some_regex/gi),
    result = test ? test[0] : 'default_value';
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot, I'm already using `||` to do similar things, but I never thought of putting the 'default value' into an array, that's a great tip!

Comment: @YemSalat Glad to help! I also added an alternate solution, since this could get a bit clunky if you want to grab capture groups or something.

Comment: Although it looks a bit 'hacky' when I want to grab the group match out of the regex.
`var result = (someString.match(/some_regex/gi) || [,'default_value'])[1]; // comma before the 'default value'`

[Update] Yeah.. :) Thanks again!